# Defence from electrostatic discharges

Tags: led, esd

I work with SLED (superluminiscent light-emitting diodes). Datasheet said me that I must to avoid electrostatic discharges when I work with SLED. So I want to connect cathode with anode of SLED and will begin to mount SLED. It will be enough for safe operations (without electrostatic discharges) with SLED?

Comment: Wrap a wire around your wrist and connect the end to earth - radiator, water pipe or anything metallic that is earthed in your house.

Comment: I know this way, but I'm not sure that any metallic things around me are connected with earth, so I asked this question

Comment: CAUTION: Always add a 1 Meg resistor in series with any wire you wrap around any part of you and connect to ground.  1 Meg is small enough to bleed off any charge but large enough so that if you somehow come in contact with high voltage you don't provide a nice path for the current.  Commercial wrist straps have the resistor built in so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: If you short the anode and cathode of the SLED, from the point that you short it it will be safe from ESD.  The trouble is if you are not sure you are charge-free how do you short it without potentially damaging it? (Pun intended.)

Comment: Ok, I have a ESD wrist band. But, when I will be mount SLED, my soldering tool might be contain a statical charge, isn't it? I want to protect SLED from it

Comment: Many soldering irons have ESD safe tips, but in case yours doesn't just touch the tip to something grounded before soldering.  (Whatever you attach the wrist strap to should work.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need an ESD wrist band:

[image]

Those go on your arm, as you certainly have guessed. The terminal should be connected to a ground potential through 1 Mega-ohm resistor. Don't connect to ground directly as suggested in comments, unless you have high tolerance to electric shocks. Use a ESD plug:

[image]